# textview and button to contract when the keyboard is shown

Tags: android, layout

have a look at the code from an xml file where i am using two textviews and one button...
the problem is that when i click on a textview the default keyboard appears and half of the second textview and the button hides...then u have to manually close the keyboard and then u will b able to click on the send button...

my question is how can i perform that when the keyboard is shown the whole view slides up or shrinks so that the button is visible....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etRecieverNum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
         >
    </EditText>



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMessageToBeSent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.82"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
         />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put

```
  <activity
  android:name="yourActivity"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

in your manifest.. or put

```
 adjustResize instead of adjustPan
```

**adjustResize**
The activity’s main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

**adjustPan**
The activity’s main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

Comment: yes that helped....but one more thing...when i type in the textview the text goes on and on and the new line dont begins... i mean when the space or the width of the textview ends it should come to the next line but it goes on straight

Answer (score 1):

Inside your Manifest file give some thing like this under the activity

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

You can also refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for further details on windowSoftInputMode

Comment: yes that helped....but one more thing...when i type in the textview the text goes on and on and the new line dont begins... i mean when the space or the width of the textview ends it should come to the next line but it goes on straight